# Assigning a User when creating a Business Unit with Fuel-SOAP

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I am using Fuel-SOAP (via fuel-soap npm) to create a new Business Unit. I am able to create a new business unit but am not able to attach an existing user to it in the same API call. I keep getting this error:

```
[ { StatusCode: 'Error',
       StatusMessage: 'An error occured while attempting to save one of the account\'s subobjects.',
       OrdinalID: '0',
       ErrorCode: '6',
       NewID: '1446261',
       Object: [Object],
       CreateResults: [Object] } ]
```

My API call looks like this:

```
var opt = {
"Name" : "New BU Name",
"ParentID": 12345,
"Email": "email@email.com",
"FromName": "First Last",
"AccountType": "BUSINESS_UNIT",
"AccountUsers": {"AccountUser":[{ID:12345}]}
}

SoapClient.create('BusinessUnit', opt, null, function(err, response){}
```

Seems to be an issue with the AccountUsers property. If I omit this property or if I submit an invalid value with it, the business unit gets created as expected.

Comment: you should not pass a Null object into the Objects array on the Create method.